# Watir - Span elements

Tags: watir, html

```
<span id="olLabelCUSTOMERSALL">Text - ALL
```

In the GUI I see `All` and I can select this via

```
browser_ie.span(:id, "olLabelCONTACTSALL").click
```

I then tried to set this to a variable like

```
text1 = browser_ie.span(:id, "olLabelCONTACTSALL")
```

and I thought I would get `ALL` but I don't.

In the html screen shot what is `Text - ALL`? Is that an attribute of the Span element? How would I capture the text `ALL` from this

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the watir span element when you do:

```
text1 = browser_ie.span(:id, "olLabelCONTACTSALL")
```

If you want the text, use the element's `text` method:

```
text1 = browser_ie.span(:id, "olLabelCONTACTSALL").text
```